# Android Sygic intent

Tags: android, android-intent, sygic

I followed the instructions at http://dev.sygic.com/documentation/custom-url-schema/ & http://help.sygic.com/entries/22207668-Developers-Only-Sygic-implementation-to-your-app-Android-SDK-iPhone-SDK-Url-Handler-

I am passing the coordinates to Sygic 12.991030334592057 as latitude and 77.80791163444519 as longitude.

Another com.sygic.aura://coordinate|12.9138|77.6680|drive

However Sygic says 'The coordinates are outside the map.'

```
        String str = "http://com.sygic.aura/coordinate|" + latitude + "|"
            + longitude + "|" + type.toString();        
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(str)));
```

I also tried

```
        String str = "com.sygic.aura://coordinate|" + latitude + "|"
            + longitude + "|" + type.toString();        
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(str)));
```

**EDIT:**
The type is enum. type.toString shows drive as the string.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: how U solve the problem? because i am also facing this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Got the same problem. As enli was saying, the order of the lat,lon params is the opposite. This code worked for me:

```
String str = "com.sygic.aura://coordinate|" + lon + "|" + lat + "|" + type.toString();        
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(str)));
```

in my phone, this example call launched sygic and started navigation:

```
com.sygic.aura://coordinate|-3.588678|37.176278|drive
```

Hope it helps

Comment: how it start navigation i mean does it makes a route for your current location and the custom latitude longitudes?

Comment: it starts sygic app, and lets you choose the start point of the route. By default, it is "my location".

Comment: it start sygic but not making a route from my current location to the given lat lon.

Comment: The order of coordinates is a bit confusing IMO

Answer (score -1):

There is nothing wrong with your code. Have you made sure that those values of longitude and latitude are correct? With which application you got those co-ordinates?

I was working on the same code today and it seems that I had used longitude at the place of latitude and vice versa. Try interchanging the co-ordinates. That worked for me when I was in the same boat as yours. If that is not the case, make sure that you have Sygic maps for that location by manually navigating to that location by navigating to that location from Menu > Navigate to... > GPS coordinates.